# How do I create hidden divs, and how do I use swf files in them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, hidden

I've been having a hard time finding a good tutorial for this:

I'm trying to make it so when a thumbnail image is clicked, a hidden div shows up above it. I also would like it to be able to be closed. I tried to do popups prior to this, but the swf files loaded with the page instead of the popup. Can that be avoided with a hidden div?

How would I go about making my divs?
Example code:

```
<div class="work"><h4>"1" - Animation SOUND</h4>
<img src="images/thumb/bazinga_thumb.png" ></a></div>

<div class="work"><h4>"2" - Animation SOUND</h4>
<img src="images/thumb/2_thumb.png" ></a></div>

<div class="work"><h4>"3" - Animation SOUND</h4>
<img src="images/thumb/3_thumb.png" ></a></div>
```

I'm looking for CSS and JS options!

Comment: Explain `but the swf files loaded with the page instead of the popup` and have a look at tooltip plugins like qtip2.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div id="flashHolder" style="display:hidden;">
<embed src="thing.swf"></embed>
</div>
<img onclick="showFlash();" src="image.png" />
<script>
function showFlash()
{
document.getElementById("flashHolder").style.display="auto";
}
</script>
```

i hope i could help! =)